# MapStruct / Java - Conversion Timestamp to Instant

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have this Mapper, and I want to convert a Entity to a DTO.
My Entity contains the variable createdDate who is an Instant and my DTO contains commentedDate who is a Timestamp.

I don't know how it's possible to convert automatically the Instant to Timestamp whit MapStruct.

```
public interface BlogMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "userId", source = "user.id"),
            @Mapping(target = "commentedDate", source = "createdDate")
    })
    BlogDto entityToDto(final Comment entity);
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901178/mapstruct-localdatetime-to-instant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is really similar to [Mapstruct LocalDateTime to Instant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901178/mapstruct-localdatetime-to-instant). The only difference is that this asks for conversion between `Timestamp` and `Instant`.

The best way to achieve that is to provide a custom mapping method. For example:

```
@Mapper
public interface BlogMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "userId", source = "user.id"),
    @Mapping(target = "commentedDate", source = "createdDate")
    BlogDto entityToDto(final Comment entity);

    default Timestamp map(Instant instant) {
        return instant == null ? null : Timestamp.from(instant);
    }
}
```

Using this all `Instant`(s) would be mapped to `Timestamp`. You can also extract that method into a static util class and then use it via `Mapper#uses`